# The difference between { } and [ ] in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

What is the main difference between { } and [ ] ?

I want to know when to use it and how stores the data

```
education: [
    {
      school: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      fieldofstudy: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      to: {
        type: Date
      },
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      description: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ]


social: {
    youtube: {
      type: String
    },
    twitter: {
      type: String
    },
    facebook: {
      type: String
    },
    linkedin: {
      type: String
    },
    instagram: {
      type: String
    }
  }
```

I would love to see some examples to understand where to use it and when not to use it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+arrays+and+objects

Comment: Though the question likely illustrates a lack of understanding for JavaScript itself and the other references will help, then I would also suggest reading the MongoDB manual section on [Data Modeling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/) as a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

`{ }` can contain index data (with string indexes), while `[ ]` can only contain unindexed data (which numerically indexed by default).

As your example suggests,

1. Here, data is on 0 index by default:

   ```
   education: [{
     school: {
       type: String,
       required: true
     },
     fieldofstudy: {
       type: String,
       required: true
     },
     from: {
       type: Date,
       required: true
     },
     to: {
       type: Date
     },
     current: {
       type: Boolean,
       default: false
     },
     description: {
       type: String
     }
   }]
   ```
2. Here data have string indexed

   ```
   social: {
       youtube: {
         type: String
       },
       twitter: {
         type: String
       },
       facebook: {
         type: String
       },
       linkedin: {
         type: String
       },
       instagram: {
         type: String
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: `while [ ] can only contain unindexed data` This is unfortunately false. Arrays can contain pretty much the same sort of key-value pairs as objects, it's just an abuse of their structure to do so. Also, your code doesn't look great, strings require delimiters.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I know its "(which numerically indexed by default)" as added.
Also, your code doesn't look great, strings require delimiters.  I didn't get??